# Running flask with fcgi

Tags: python, flask

I'm reading through http://fgimian.github.io/blog/2014/02/14/serving-a-python-flask-website-on-hostmonster/ , trying to deploy a flask app on shared hosting.

I'm using https://github.com/wdm0006/cookiecutter-flask as my app , and I'm at the stage where I'm working to modify the fcgi script:

```
#!/home/fots/.virtualenv/flaskage/bin/python
import sys

from flup.server.fcgi import WSGIServer

sys.path.insert(0, '/home/fots/flaskage')
from application import create_app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app('production')
    WSGIServer(app).run()
```

In particular the cookiecutter is run using a manage.py file (https://github.com/wdm0006/cookiecutter-flask/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.app_name%7D%7D/manage.py) and contains:

```
if os.environ.get("{{cookiecutter.app_name | upper}}_ENV") == 'prod':
    app = create_app(ProdConfig)
else:
    app = create_app(DevConfig)

HERE = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEST_PATH = os.path.join(HERE, 'tests')

manager = Manager(app)


........

if __name__ == '__main__':
manager.run()
```

I'm not sure how to modify the manage.py to run it using the fcgi script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. `manage.py` is for managing the local development.  `fcgi.py` is for setting up the production app.  `fcgi.py` already imports the app factory and tells it what environment to use (`create_app('production')`), so unless there's something wrong with that call you already have everything you need.